# How can I run a python script without the console window opening?

Tags: python, windows

When run, my python script creates a command window, how can I stop the console from appearing without using the `.pyw` extension as this has not worked. My program is designed to run on a Windows PC.

Comment: Uee the `pythonw.exe` binary instead of `python.exe`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, hence my mention in the question.

Comment: "_has not worked_" and "_does not seem to work for me_" by itself aren't very popular sentences around here, as you probably guessed by now judging by the amount of help received, which is none.  Explain the problem, mention what you've tried and be specific about any errors you may have or were you got stuck and you may get lucky.